# How to get the specific value from mysql database using pdo fetch?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Database table name `userclass` has this column : `user, class, date`

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM userclass WHERE user = :user");
$stmt->bindValue(":user", "James");
$stmt->execute();
```

I want to get the value of class and date in which the user is 'James' and print it using php

```
for($i=0; $i< the amount of row in which the user is 'James'; $i++){
  echo the class from database;
  echo the date from database;
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks for the answer..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use fetch   eg  fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo $row['class'];
  echo $row['date'];
}
```